# ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT when using WinUSB WritePipe

Tags: winusb

I often get `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT` errors using the `WinUSB WritePipe` function.  This would seem to indicate that there is a timeout, but if I wait a period of time and try again I'm never able to write.  I'm writing in 64 byte chucks to the USB device and often don't have problems.  Once I start getting the error, I may have to unplug the USB and and close my app before trying again.  Has anybody experienced this problem?